# Update row value based on the most recent value of the previous row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

Suppose I have a pandas DataFrame:

| RowNum | PageName | OfInterest |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | home | False |
| 1 | photo | False |
| 2 | list | True |
| 3 | photo | False |
| 4 | photo | False |
| 5 | photo | False |
| 6 | home | False |
| 7 | photo | False |

`OfInterest` value for all rows with `PageName=photo` should be set to `True` only if they follow `PageName=list`.

In my desired output, rows `3,4,5` will be changed, but not rows `1, 7`:

| RowNum | PageName | OfInterest |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | home | False |
| 1 | photo | False |
| 2 | list | True |
| 3 | photo | *True* |
| 4 | photo | *True* |
| 5 | photo | *True* |
| 6 | home | False |
| 7 | photo | False |

I attempted to do this using `apply()` but it seems that I cannot access the most recently changed values.

```
def changeInterest(x):
  followsOfInterest = (x['PageName'] == 'photo') and (x['PrevOfInterest'])
  return followsOfInterest or x['OfInterest']

df['PrevOfInterest'] = df['OfInterest'].shift(-1)
df['PrevOfInterest'] = df[['PageName', 'OfInterest', 'PrevOfInterest']].apply(changeInterest, axis=1)
```

I know I can accomplish the same using a loop, but I would like to find a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try replace and ffill here , then just compare if the ffilled value is `'list'`

```
s = df['PageName'].replace('photo',np.nan).ffill().eq('list')|df['OfInterest']
df['OfInterest'] = s
```

---

```
print(df)

   RowNum PageName  OfInterest
0       0     home       False
1       1    photo       False
2       2     list        True
3       3    photo        True
4       4    photo        True
5       5    photo        True
6       6     home       False
7       7    photo       False
```